# Create XML Amazon Envelope in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create XML file necessary for Amazon's feed but getting error when creating AmazonEnvelope

```
             XElement _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ = new XElement(@"AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""amzn-envelope.xsd""");
            _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_.Save("D:\\_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_.xml");
```

The error says:

```
 +      $exception  {"The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."}    System.Exception {System.Xml.XmlException}
```

Problem is, there have to be space. Does anyone have solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use object model instead of "everything-in-plain-text" method

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var elm = new XElement("AmazonEnvelope",
                       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", ns),
                       new XAttribute(ns + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd"));
```